# How to do integration of Kartik-v Export widget in yii2 basic to export table data?

Tags: yii, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, yii2

I am a newbie to yii2 and learning it. I am trying to integrate the export widget developed by kartik. I have installed it using composer. But when I am trying to use it in my project, I am not able to export any data. It just shows two buttons one is for list of columns and second is for export as excel, pdf,csv. when I am clicking on export as csv nothing is happening. I have spend around 4-5 hours to integrate it but nothing is in my favor. can anyone provide the best tutorial or any suggestion how to integrate it in my project.

Link of the widget is -: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-export

```
  <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\grid\GridView;
    use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
    //use kartik\grid\GridView;
     use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

      /* @var $this yii\web\View */
      /* @var $searchModel app\models\CattleDataSearch */
      /* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

      $this->title = 'Cattle Profile';
      $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
       $gridColumns = [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         'cattleform_id',
         'farmer_id',
         'cattle_owner',
         'cattle_id',
         'type_of_cattle',
         'origin',
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
       ]; 
        echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'columnSelectorOptions'=>[
        'label' => 'Columns',
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
    ],
    'fontAwesome' => true,
    'dropdownOptions' => [
        'label' => 'Export All',
        'class' => 'btn btn-success'
    ]
]);

  echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
  ]);

  ?>
 <div class="cattle-data-index">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
<hr style="background: #C0C0C0; height: 2px;"/>

 </div>

 <div class="cattle-form-index" style="border: #FFFFFF solid 1px;       border-radius: 10px; padding: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #888888; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: white; ">

     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
     <?= $form->field($model, 'cattleform_id') ?>

       <?= $form->field($model, 'cattle_id') ?>

     <?= $form->field($model,'type_of_cattle')-    >dropDownList(array('Cow'=>'Cow','Buffalo'=>'Buffalo'),  ['prompt'=>'Select....']) ?> 
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">

 <?= $form->field($model,'origin')->dropDownList(array('Gifted'=>'Gifted','Home'=>'Home','Same Village'=>'Same Village','Outside'=>'Outside','Other'=>'Other'),['prompt'=>'Select....']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'natural_of_ai')->dropDownList(array('Natural'=>'Natural','AI'=>'AI','No Information'=>'No Information','NA'=>'NA','Other'=>'Other'),['prompt'=>'Select....']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'delivery')->dropDownList(array('Home'=>'Home','Outside'=>'Outside','No Information'=>'No Information','NA'=>'NA'),['prompt'=>'Select....']) ?> 





     <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>

        <?php
       if(isset    ($_GET['farmer_id']))
      {
        echo Html::a('AddNew',    ['create','farmer_id'=>$_GET['farmer_id']], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo Html::a('AddNew', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);

    }



     ?>

</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>




</div>
```

On fresh yii installation I am getting the following error-:[image]

Comment: Have you checked [demonstration](http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo) page of Kartik-v/Yii2 -export?

Comment: yeah .. still not able to integrate it.:(

Comment: show what you tried?

Comment: I have followed the same instruction as given on the github account. Installed using composer then make changes to my view file only like add use statement then create $gridcolumns variable and echoing the export menu.

Comment: yeah, show code of gridview.

Comment: echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]);

Comment: and export menu configuration, please edit post, don't add comments.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. But I didn't make any changes to the ExportMenu.php because i haven't see any comment to make changes in ExportMenu.php. Please let me know what kind of changes you want for me to do in ExportMenu.php

Comment: I am able help you after inspecting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked main.php in config,can you try the following code there

'modules'=>['gridview'=>['class'=>'\kartik\grid\module',],],

and do check whether the pop up's are blocked in your Browser.

Comment: I have added this module in my code and allowed popup for all websites but not working.

Comment: You can add this code ( check target)                                                        echo ExportMenu::widget( [
                                     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                                     'columns'      => $gridColumns,
                                     'target'       => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK,
                                 ] );

Comment: Now do you have any error messages, if so please share it.